# C++ Visual Studio - How to tab at end of line to add comment

Tags: c++, visual-studio, tabs

This is a stupid and frustrating thing. Working with VS 2019 after a few years away, and I cannot remember the option to allow me to tab at the end of a line to add an end-of-line comment. The cursor just sits there when I hit tab at the end of

```
int frustrationLevel = 99;
```

I want to tab after the semicolon dagnabit!

```
int frustrationLevel = 99;    // omg please help me!
```

I know this used to be possible.

TIA!

Comment: This seems to work fine for me on Visual Studio 2019. Although I am using: Version 16.7.19 to keep all production systems having the same version installed.

Comment: yeah, i am guessing you have the magic option set...ie, the one i cannot remember

Comment: I've never had this problem with VS, ever.  And I've never had to set any special options for this either.

Answer (score 0):

After comparing option after option with a previous version of VS where the tab worked as desired, I found an option that was set

Options -> Text Editor -> C/C++ -> Code Style -> Formatting -> General ::
Automatically indent when I type a tab.

Unchecking this option fixed my issue.

Comment: Hi ,glad to know you've found the solution to resolve this issue! Please consider  accepting it as an answer to change its status to Answered. See [can I answer my own question..](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), Just a reminder :)